# Internet connection drops every 10 minutes (exactly)

Tags: networking, router, internet, freeze, dhcp

Since I've moved to a new apartment a few months ago and changed my I ISP (the one shared with other apartments in building - same router) I experience internet drops (ethernet) every ten minutes, quite exactly.

There seems to be some variation, but here's an example (I deduce this from when I `ping 8.8.8.8`):

```
4:10:27 pm (First) Drop.
4:11:54 pm Reconnect (after 87s; normally between 0.5 and 4 min).
4:21:09 pm Drop (after uptime of 555s or 9min 15s).
4:25:04 pm Reconnect (after 235s).
4:34:15 pm Drop (after uptime of 555s again!).
etc.

(It is possible that the drop time is slightly earlier...)
```

The uptime interval is quite constant (between 540 and 590), while the downtime varies more (between 0.5 and 4 mins). During these drops I cannot browse or receive emails in my mail program, etc, while the router itself is reachable at all times; the connection monitor states a "green" connection.

Other tenants know this problem too, but it doesn't seem to be that grave with them (drops less often, if any at all, faster connection time?).

I've had a look at our router:

- IPs are set to static, so my laptop gets the same IP every time it connects. I therefore rule out IP interference between the different devices.
- DHCP lease is set to 10 days. So a too short DHCP lease time can also be ruled out...
- I restarted the router, nothing changed. (I am not allowed to reset, because the landlord has his phone line through said router.)

**What could be the problem? Is it more likely my laptop (never a drop at the old apartment...), the router or the ISP?**

*My setup:*

```
+Device+                +Connection type to next device+

Street (ISP)            via fibre-optic
to Modem                via Ethernet Cable
to Router               via Ethernet Cable (=EC)
to "public" Switch      via EC        (also to other tenants wall ports and from there to their routers and devices [directly and over those routers] probably via EC or WiFi)
to Wall port in my room via EC
to my switch            via EC
(to Dock*               via EC)
to my Laptop            via EC (or* USB 2.0).

*sometimes I use a USB Docking Station [Sabrent DS-RICA], but the problem stays the same, whether I do or don't.
```

- Modem: DKT Comega 97601 FTTH Gateway (on its bottom: "next gen snmp, ftth-node, wan [?!], no VOIP, no CATV")
- Router: FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7390, only Ethernet activated and "DSL deactivated" (no DSL because fibre-opic to ethernet).
- Laptop: MacBook Pro 13'' Early 2011 with OS X 10.11 El Capitan.

**EDIT:**

!!Only *entries 3 and 5* (bold first sentences) might be relevant; **skip rest & go to UPDATE below!!**

1. There seems to be a difference where I use my laptop docking station or plug in the ethernet cable directly into my laptop: With the latter setup the reconnection time is shorter and more constant, around 13 seconds instead of 0.5 up to 4 minutes... But the drops still occur and last for a similar amount of time with both setups.
2. Bringing the router time and laptop time in line with each other (laptop gets its time now from router; see below) did not solve the problem.
3. **The router's public IP remains the same before and after the drops.** (The same goes for the internal IP of my laptop [since it's static].)
4. The problem also occurs when I'm the only device connected to the router (apart from a printer and a second FRITZ!Box connected to the first; the second router and the printer both have static IPs on the first router).
5. **During a drop Wireshark registers many *TCP Retransmission* entries (black bars).**

   When I run Wireshark on the ethernet connection, there are no DHCP processes after a drop (apart from DHCP v6: Solicit XID). When I plug out and plug in my ethernet cable (out of and into the docking station), Wireshark registers the following DHCP processes (not quite Discover-Request-Offer-Acknowledgement):

   ```
   +Packet No.+  +Time+  +Info+

   7             14      DHCP Request
   38            15      DHCP Request
   48            18      DHCP Request
   59            22      DHCP Discover
   65            24      DHCP Discover
   68            26      DHCP Discover
   73            31      DHCP Discover
   74            31      DHCP Offer (sends static, expected IP)
   76            32      DHCP Request
   77            33      DHCP Request
   80            35      DHCP Request
   81            35      DHCP Acknowledgement
   ```

   When the ethernet cable is plugged into the laptop directly this process is (way faster and less messy):

   ```
   +Packet No.+  +Time+  +Info+

   5             0       DHCP Request
   46            1       DHCP Request
   47            1       DHCP Acknowledgement
   ```
6. The "public" switch has 8 ethernet ports, port 1 being the port where the signal enters, port 4 being the port which delivers my signal (to a wall port in the router room). Switching the latter ethernet cable to another port (e.g. port 5) or connecting my laptop directly to such a port does not solve the problem. So the switch seems to work fine (see UPDATE below). Connecting to the router directly did not solve the problem either (see UPDATE below). I believe that all other tenants, except me, use another router between the FRITZ!Box router (or rather between their wall port) and their devices. **Could not using an additional router be the problem?** (Probably *no*; see UPDATE below.)
7. Information about the Router: Router *internal log* does not show anything when my drops occur; no unexpected log entries at all. *Firmware* FRITZ!OS 06.85, up to date. *Self-Diagnosis* ok. *NetBIOS* denial and *Teredo* denial active. Router *firewall* off. *IPv6* deactivated, *IPv4* only. Only the *ports* 443 (HTTPS), 5060 (Phone, SIP), 7078-7109 (Phone, RTP) and 8089 (TR069) are open. All other ports closed; I can confirm this by port scans from the outside. E.g. port 80 is not open. **Should port 80 be open?** (Maybe does not matter?!) Additionally I am going to write an email to the FRITZ!Box support (*pending*, see below, UPDATE2).
8. The landlord says that he experiences *phone connection drops* (he's connected via ethernet cable to the router („FON“); maybe VOIP?) from time to time. Also his internet connection drops the same way (see UPDATE below), but he notices this not as often, since he browses not that frequent.He says that both problems started to occur when the building was connected to the new fibre-optic line of the city (before probably connected via phone line). **Could this phone trouble be connected to my problem?** (Probably *yes*; see UPDATE below.) **Could my problem have something to do with the fibre-optic?** (Probably *no*; see UPDATE below.)
9. Information about the connection at my old apartment: At the previous apartment I’ve had never any problems connecting and staying connected. First setup there was `Wall port (Antenna socket [≠ Satellite])-->Modem (probably DSL?)-->Netgear Router-->Laptop`, the (second) and most recent setup there was `Wall port (Antenna; now same port as TV)-->ISP brand Modem-Router (?) (Phone cables also went in there)-->Laptop`, same ISP with either setup, but a different one from now. I plugged in the ethernet cable and it worked instantly and flawlessly...

**UPDATE!!**

Yesterday evening I've connected to the router directly with an ethernet cable, but the same problem occurred. Then I had the idea of plugging the very same cable into the *modem: No more internet drops, flawless browsing!!* (Just some observations: A) I couldn't reach the router from the modem [naturally, since I'm not in the router network]. B) I had an IPv6 and different public IPv4 [same reason]. C) Wireshark registered constantly ARP protocol "Who has... [fill in IP]" entries from the origin "BrocadeC_1c:14:00", nothing else, but it worked. **Is C) normal?**)

This is ok and would be a workaround, but I am not satisfied yet: That router has to work; especially since I had the chance to install Wireshark on my landlords computer with is also connected to the FRITZ!Box router (via the same public switch as I am) *and can confirm now, that the problem also occurs on other devices* (also on mobile devices connected to this FRITZ!Box via another WLAN router [tested via `ping`]).

**From the information in the two paragraphs above, I conclude, that the problem is with the router.** (*ISP and modem ruled out by directly connecting to the modem, my laptop [and all other attached devices] ruled out due to Wireshark test on second laptop, Switch and cables ruled out by directly connecting to the router.*) I therefore reset (wiped) the routers configuration (back to factory settings) and directly connected to the router via ethernet cable: **Problem gone.** Unfortunately, I had to reconfigure the router, because my landlords phone goes through the router. Since I didn't dare to do this myself, I uploaded the old configuration file to the router: **Problem occurs again... So the problem lies within that specific configuration?!**

Three questions (and one minor one in the first paragraph of this update):

**1. Is my conclusion correct?**

**2. What would you recommend me to do?**

**3. Are my landlords phone problems (EDIT 8 above) connected to this?**

**UPDATE 2**

I tried reconfiguring (manually and automatic): As soon as I change even the tiniest detail of the FRITZ!Box configuration (e.g. turn off WLAN or add phone number) on the reset FRITZ!Box (where there is no problem), the problem reoccurs... It's so strange. I'm nearly done for: **I've written to the FRITZ!Box support now and am waiting for their answer...**

**UPDATE 3**

We switched providers and are now differently connected to the network (they got there own devices to transform the input "from the street" to Ethernet cable), also they use their own router/modems. So all problems have disappeared. But since I consider disappeared problems not as solved, I'll leave this question open...!

Comment: I know this is going to sound weird, but check the time on all devices, and make sure it is set correctly.

Comment: @LPChip Thank you for your answer. You mean the system time? I'll try, but there are quite a lot devices, including printers... :S

Comment: The system time on your pc and router. Printers do not need to be checked. Only the devices that have network loss and the router(s).

Comment: @LPChip OK, I've done that: I've set my laptop (via the time/date menu in the system preferences) to get it's time from now on from the FRITZ!Box router - which itself gets the time from `0.europe.pool.ntp.org` and shares it over its network via `192.168.0.1` or `fritz.box`. I then updated my laptop's time manually (to be sure) with `sudo ntpdate -u fritz.box` in my mac's terminal.app. I'll monitor my connection now and post any results here.

Comment: Does your public IP address change after the drops?

Comment: @LPChip Drops occur in the same manner and even at the same time (now always on the third minute of every 10 minutes) as before.

Comment: @DavidPostill No, my/our/the router's public IP is the same before and after my drops.

Comment: The Support article [DSL connection drops frequently](https://en.avm.de/service/fritzbox/fritzbox-7369/knowledge-base/publication/show/41_DSL-connection-drops-frequently/) might be useful. My guess is that you might be sharing your cable with another device or that there are some other modulations on the line for which the docking station is more sensitive than the desktop.

Comment: If the issue is occurring on multiple devices then it's unlikely the issue is with your devices. Do you have an old router you could try? If the problem persists after trying a different router and Ethernet cable then it's probably best your ISP send an engineer over to check the line/ports in your flat and also test the connections at the exchange on your street.

Comment: @harrymc Thank you for your answer. DSL is turned off on the router since before I moved into the building. 1. Should that be turned on? 2. Could it be that the router confuses the devices when I plug in the **same** ethernet cable directly into the laptop instead of the docking station, or vice versa (Docking Station and Laptop have their own static IP on the router, each device via its own MAC address)? 3. Could the problem be caused by one of the two switches or by another device connected to those switches? 4. What do you mean by "modulation which the dock is more sensitive to"?

Comment: 1. What is the difference between DSL and Ethernet in your case? 2. Unlikely but shouldn't cause rhythmic drops, 3. Yes, 4. Some changes in the signal or drop in voltage or whatever.

Comment: @Myles Thank you for your answer. Well, the other people don't seem to care much about this problem - so I reckon it is not that dominant on their devices or doesn't occur at all - or they don't use the internet that often (if you use the browser [loading of new content etc.] within the uptime, you'll never notice the drops), so they are not that annoyed by that problem. Additionally I don't have any ping data from them. So I am actually not sure if I am the only one or just the most annoyed... No, I don't have an old router, but I'll try to connect directly (no switch) to the router, now...

Comment: You mention DSL deactivated. Is your router/modem such that the wan port is not an ethernet port? and as such you have the other router's ethernet port plugged into the lan port? If that's the case, your router is only a switch, and DHCP and stuff is set by the other router.

Comment: @harrymc 1. There's a modem next to the FRITZ!Box router which seems to "translate" the fiber-optic signal "from the street" (ISP) to the router (via ethernet cable). On the router there are options to choose from: "Wired to external router or modem" is chosen instead of "Wired to DSL Connection" or "Wired to cable modem". So I guess the DSL part happens on the modem? 3. Those switches don't have IPs, but there are other routers (& devices, directly & via those routers - but each with own static IP) connected to the "public" switch. What of them is most likely to cause the problem? 4. I see.

Comment: @LPChip Same answer as to harrymc: // There's a modem next to the FRITZ!Box router which seems to "translate" the fiber-optic signal "from the street" (ISP) to the router (via ethernet cable!!). On the router there are options to choose from: "Wired to external router or modem" is chosen instead of "Wired to DSL Connection" or "Wired to cable modem". So I guess the DSL part happens on the modem? // It's Street (ISP)-fibre-optic>modem-ethernet cable!!>router... So the DHCP part happens on the modem? But DHCP is on and actively distributing IPs on the router...

Comment: If it's converted from fiber directly to Ethernet, then DSL is not involved in any way, shape, nor form. DSL is almost exclusively for copper landline phone WAN connections (the fiber connection might be called GPON or simple fiber-Ethernet). But higher-layer functions such as NAT or DHCP *might* be done by the fiber modem. It would be interesting to check in Wireshark exactly how many DHCP offers you receive in reply to a single discover...

Comment: @harrymc Addition to 3.: The problem also occurs, when I am the only device connected to the router (apart from a printer and a second FRITZ!Box connected to the first; the second router and the printer both have static IPs on the first printer).

Comment: @grawity Thank you for the clarification! I've run Wireshark and received **only one offer**, but the order of the whole process was different from the expected Discover-Offer-Request-Acknowledge: see fifth EDIT entry within question!

Comment: To all: Additional lead (EDIT 6 above): I believe that all other tenants, except me, use another router between the FRITZ!Box router (or rather between their wall port) and their devices. **Could not using an additional router be the problem?**

Comment: From your additional information, the problem seems to be between your computer and the router, and not between the router and the ISP. The obvious step would be to log into the router (Fritzboxes can be rooted), and find out what's happening on its side, or to replace the router with another router and see if the problem persists. If that is not possible, I'd run Wireshark and look for *everything* that's odd. My money is on some effect in the Fritzbox, possibly due to misconfiguration, or maybe a bug.

Comment: @dirkt Many thanks for your answer! 1. I've logged onto the webinterface of the FRITZ!Box router and looked through all that's there: Everything worthy to mention I've written into my question above (EDIT 7). (Also @ Myles:) 2. I will connect my old Netgear router (not as sophisticated webinterface as the FRITZ!Box) to the modem on Saturday night and see if the problem persists. 3. I am new to Wireshark (and all of this): What would you define as odd log/packet entries within Wireshark?

Comment: If the internet/phone connection drops (which means everybody has connection problems at the same time, contrary to what you wrote in the beginning), this would point to a problem between router/modem and ISP. Does the **modem** have a web interface? What brand of modem is it?

Comment: @dirkt Sorry for that contradiction - it's a very contradicting situation for me... The only thing written on the modem is "FTTH Gateway" (quite small). I think this is a "off brand" modem of my city (which owns the fibre-optic lines in the streets and provides this modem too; but maybe the ISP has access to it?). I myself don't think that I can access it - or at least I wouldn't know how (?) or over which IP...

Comment: What ISP are you using? Check in your router configuration page what the default gateway is and try to connect to the IP address. The default gateway of your router should be your modem. If you could get some details from the config page of the modem it might help. I suspect your modem may be DOCSIS 2.0 while your ISP might have moved on to DOCSIS 3.0

Comment: @LayneBernardo Thank you for your message. ISP is the Swiss iway.ch collaborating with the electricity provider of my city (the latter owns the fiber-opitc lines beneath the streets and probably the modem). I couldn't find the default gateway on the router (no static IP route configured), but on all connected devices the default gateway is the routers IP, so the router itself. Is this a satisfying answer for you, or has the router itself to have a def. gateway? I wouldn't know how to reach the modem... I don't know the IP of it... I might contact the ISP about DOCSIS.

Comment: @dirkt: Modem brand: **DKT Comega 97601 FTTH Gateway** (on its bottom: "next gen snmp, ftth-node, wan [?!], no VOIP, no CATV". **Could this be relevant to my problem (see UPDATE in question above)?** If it had a webinterface, how would I reach that? (I couldn't connect to the "router IP" [≠FRITZ!Box IP] displayed in the internet preferences when directly connected to modem...)

Comment: @LayneBernardo: Modem information added in the comment above. Its a modem by **DKT Comega**. On their page (https://dktcomega.com/docsis-3-1/) they state that they use DOCSIS 3.1, but I'm not sure if the modem is up to date. How could I check that? **Is this still relevant after my UPDATE (see last section of question, please)?**

Comment: @all: **UPDATE** added to question! Thank you for any answers and your time! :D

Comment: Yes, the problem is in the specific configuration. Sit down with your landlord, configure it manually for what the landlord needs. If the problem occurs again, start over, test at each step if the problem occurs, so you can pin down the configuration step that causes it. BTW, you can also write your own answer to your question (and accept it), and detailed description of what you did may be helpful to others. Comments are not guaranteed to be permanent.

Comment: Thank you @dirkt for your confirming post!! :D I will sit down with him and post my solution as answer afterwards.

Comment: @dirkt and @ all: Well I tried and tried: As soon as I change even the tiniest detail of the FRITZ!Box configuration on the reset FRITZ!Box (where there is no problem), the problem reoccurs... It's so illogical. I've written to the FRITZ!Box support and am waiting for their answer...